# Minimum of int array using recursion C++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to use recursion to find the minimum integer in an array.

This is my code:

```
int minArray(int* array, int size){
    if (size == 0){
        return array[0];
    }
    int min = array[0];
    if (min > minArray(array+1,size-1)){
        min = minArray(array+1,size-1);
    }
    return min;
}
```

What is wrong with it? 
If i call the function on {1,2,3,4,5}, it will return 0.

Comment: First thing that's wrong is that recursion is the wrong approach to this task...

Comment: @keshlam i'm only doing it for practice with recursion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition is wrong. An array of zero elements has no elements, so accessing `array[0]` of it is illegal.

Also calling the function twice in this function should be avoided.

Try this:

```
int minArray(int* array, int size){
    if (size == 1){
        return array[0];
    }
    int min = array[0];
    int candidate = minArray(array+1,size-1);
    if (min > candidate){
        min = candidate;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: @Danny, please note that the function is going to lead to UB if `size` is zero.

Comment: @RSahu so should i add if (size == 0) return 0; ?

Comment: @Danny, if you can, avoid calling the function if `size` is zero. When `size` is zero, how do you define minimum?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is similar to the one of @MikeCat. I added the iterative version just for comparison purposes.

```
int min( int str[], int size)
{
  if (1==size)  // base case
  return str[0];
 else {
  int minor=min(&str[1],size-1); // each time the function is called its receives an array with an element less than the previous call.
  return str[0]<=minor ? str[0] : minor;
  }
}


// iterative approach. I have added the minor´s position indicator.
int mini(int str[], int size, int* position)
{
 int minor=str[0];
 for (int i=1;i<size;i++)
  if (str[i]<minor) {
   minor=str[i];
   *position=i;
   }
 return minor;
}
```